# Format kendoui textbox as phone number using jquery.inputmask plugin

Tags: data-binding, kendo-ui, formatting

I'm trying to format a textbox control in kendoui as phone number, using data- attributes
The backend field is string.

I made it as:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="k-textbox" 
    data-role="numerictextbox"
    data-spinner="false"
    data-format="(###) ###.####"/>
```

and

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="k-textbox" data-format="(###) ###.####"/>
```

but none works.

First one does not display any intermediary formatting characters or spaces: ( ) -
Second does not enforce digits, as well as not display any intermediary formatting characters.

Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT**

I just find out jquery.inputmask, and tried to use it. I included the script  jquery.inputmask, and added the data-inputmask attribute as below

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask-2.4.20.js"></script>
....
<input type="text" class="k-textbox" data-inputmask="'mask': '(999) 999.9999'"/>
```

but nothing happened.
How should I trigger mask enforcement? 
I don't want to use jquery call for each control like

```
$("#myctrl").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999.9999"})
```

but instead use data-attributes

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the HTML5 phone number input type.

[html5 input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware KendoUI does not have a widget or control to format input field such as phone numbers. It is planed to be incorporated soon this year, I think it has not been release yet:

http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2404523-just-a-mask-edit

In the meantime I would recommend you using one of the JQuery options available, like these 2 examples:

- https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask
- http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Thanks. I found inputmask plugin, and I want to use data-attributes, but I cannot make it work. I updated question to include add'l info. Any idea how can I accomplish what I need? Thanks.

Comment: @bzamfir update a question to ask another question is not the best way to go since your first question was already answered

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link to a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WvHE/) using the `data-inputmask` attributes that you would like to use.

You had assigned the mask in the attribute correctly..

```
<input type="text" class="k-textbox" data-inputmask="'mask': '(999) 999.9999'"/>
```

Your problem is that you never selected the elements and then applied the inputmask.  The `data-inputmask` is just an attribute that will store the mask definition, it doesn't run automatically.

You need to add this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('[data-inputmask]').inputmask();
});
```